# C loop for irregular pattern of numbers

Tags: c, for-loop

May I ask how is it possible to write a loop for the following pattern:

```
P   Q
0   1
0   2
1   2
1   3
------
2   3
2   4
3   4
3   5
------
4   5
4   6
5   6
5   7
```

I know people usually show their try first and then ask for help here but I am really stuck with this.any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: look at `P`, `Q` independently.

Comment: @amir It is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve. What is the pattern? What do you mean?

Comment: The pattern appears quite regular, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (P = 0 ; P <= 5 ; P++) {
  for (Q = P+1 ; Q <= P+2 ; Q++) {
    printf("%i %i\n", P, Q);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach but the size of the loop is invariant and only 2. Why not one loop and 2 print statments? :)
`printf("%i %i\n", P, P+1);printf("%i %i\n", P, P+2);`

Comment: I believe the task of the lesson is to learn, that you can have loops inside loops and that you have to be careful which variables to use and increment. (so to see the difference between explizit loop (like mine with variables P and Q) and implizit loop (like yours putting twice the line without using Q, loopreduction)

Comment: May I ask if the last column changes to: 4  5  4  0   5  0  5  1  how the loop will change? Thanks in forward.

Comment: if Q greater than 5 subtract 6 from Q.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* format = "%5d%5d\n";

printf("%5s%5s\n", "P", "Q");

for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
    if( i % 4 == 3 ) { 
        printf("------\n"); 
    }
    printf(format, i/2, (i+3)/2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unroll the loop by the factor 2

```
for (i=p=0, q=1; i<12/2; i++) {
    { /* body */ ; }
    q++;
    { /* body */ ; }
    p++;
}
```